# MySQL: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm getting "ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger" when updating a table containing the following trigger, but don't understand why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON my_triggering_table
FOR EACH ROW CALL my_procedure();
```

I'm away that triggers cannot use a SELECT which returns a result set, but the called procedure (and its children) use only CURSOR FOR SELECT and FETCH INTO which, I understand, is permitted.  They read, but do not modify, the triggering table.

Can anyone explain the error? (MySQL 5.5)  The called procedures below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_mark VARCHAR(4);
  DECLARE v_lat, v_lon DOUBLE;
  DECLARE eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `mark`, `lat`, `lon` FROM my_triggering_table ORDER BY `order`;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = TRUE;
  DELETE FROM my_output_table;
  OPEN my_cursor;
  loop1: LOOP
    FETCH my_cursor INTO v_mark, v_lat, v_lon;
    IF eof THEN
      LEAVE loop1;
    END IF;
    CALL my_procedure_2(v_mark, v_lat, v_lon);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE my_cursor;
END//

CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure_2(IN from_mark VARCHAR(4), IN from_lat DOUBLE, IN from_lon DOUBLE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_mark VARCHAR(4);
  DECLARE v_lat, v_lon DOUBLE;
  DECLARE eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `mark`, `lat`, `lon` FROM my_triggering_table ORDER BY `order`;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = TRUE;
  OPEN my_cursor;
  loop1: LOOP
    FETCH my_cursor INTO v_mark, v_lat, v_lon;
    IF eof THEN
      LEAVE loop1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO my_output_table(`from`, `to`, `dist`, `brg`, `lat`, `lon`)
        VALUES(from_mark
             , v_mark
             , IF(from_mark = v_mark, NULL, getDist(from_lat, from_lon, v_lat, v_lon))
             , IF(from_mark = v_mark, NULL, getBearing(from_lat, from_lon, v_lat, v_lon))
             , coord_dec2ms(from_lat, true)
             , coord_dec2ms(from_lon, false)
              );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE my_cursor;
END//
```

The UDFs called do not reference any tables.

Comment: Interesting. (I can't explain the behavior, I don't see the problem.) For debugging this, I'd first try (temporarily) commenting  out the INSERT statement in `my_procedure_2`. That would ensure that any BEFORE/AFTER INSERT trigger on my_output_table won't be fired, and also take out the user defined functions (getDist, getBearing, coord_dec2ms). I'd back out functionality until I got something to execute, and then start adding stuff back in, to find what it is that causes the error.

Comment: Curiously, it appears like you're looping through all of the rows in `my_triggering_table` in my_procedure, and for each row, my_procedure_2 is again looping through all the rows in `my_triggering_table`. So, if there are 1,000 rows in `my_triggering_table`, my_output_table would wind up with 1000*1000 = 1,000,000 rows in it. And that whole business gets done for each row modified by the UPDATE statement (There's the DELETE statement, so there would only be the 1,000,000 rows, and not N*1,000,000 rows (N = number of rows updated.) The whole thing strikes me as a bit odd.